# Angular guard based on two observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, guard, angular2-observables

I'm trying to do an "AdminGuard", that should be based on two things:

1. Is the user logged in?
2. Does the user have admin rights?

I've an `AuthService` that provides two `Observable`.

I've done the following:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IsAdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }


  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
      console.log(this.auth)

      return combineLatest([this.auth.isLoggedIn, this.auth.isAdmin]).pipe(
        take(1),
        map((authInfo) => {
          console.log(authInfo)
          if (!authInfo[0]) {
            console.error('Access denied - Unauthorized')
            return this.router.parseUrl('/auth/');
          } else if (!authInfo[1]) {
            console.error('Access denied - Admin only')
            return this.router.parseUrl('/auth/unauthorized');
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        })
      );
  }

}
```

the `console.log(this.auth)` gets called and seems to have valid values, but the second console.log never gets called and my component isn't loaded.

If I remove the guard from my route:

```
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    //canActivate: [IsAdminGuard],
  }
```

it works, so I'm pretty sure it's the IsAdminGuard that doesn't work.

I'm also displaying the some other things based on the same boolean values(some `*ngIf="authService.IsLoggedIn | async"` which are working, so I don't really understand what I messed up?

**EDIT**
Here is how I update the different values of the  IsLoggedIn/IsAdmin/IsUser, in my AuthService:

```
 constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router, private afStore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(async user => {
      console.log('handling auth')
      if (this._roleSubscription) {
        this._roleSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this._roleSubscription = undefined;
      }
      if (user) {
        this._user.next(user);
        this._isLoggedIn.next(true);
        this._roleSubscription = this.afStore.doc<Roles>(`roles/${user.uid}`).valueChanges().subscribe(role => {
          console.log('updating roles', role)
          if (role) {
            this._isAdmin.next(role.admin == true)
            this._isUser.next(role.admin == true || role.user == true);//Admin have also an heart, they are users too!
          } else {
            this._isAdmin.next(false);
            this._isUser.next(false);
          }
        });
      } else {
        this._user.next(undefined);
        this._isLoggedIn.next(false);
        this._isAdmin.next(false);
        this._isUser.next(false);
        await this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
      }
      console.log('values updated')
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the `AuthService` implementation of the observables? When are the `Observables` being fed with values? Most likely your guard is running before this, and you should move the `AuthService` logic to an `APP_INITIALIZER`

Comment: All source Observables to `combineLatest` have to emit at least once so that's where I'd look first.

Comment: @Eldar I don't think so, because since I don't see the `console.log(authInfo)`, so it's not that I miss an update, I just never get any value

Comment: If you want to emit once after both observable has emitted a value, maybe try using a `forkJoin` instead of `combineLatest`?

Comment: @PoulKruijt I added the update part of my service

Comment: What's the types of `_isAdmin` and `_isLoggedIn` props?

Comment: @WilliamJuan I can try, but I tought `forkJoin` requires the Observable to complete?

Comment: @Eldar They are `Subject<boolean>`

Comment: Nvm, I didn't know that it was a `Subject`. Maybe combine `forkJoin` with `take(1)` like this: `forkJoin([this.auth.isLoggedIn.pipe(take(1)), this.auth.isAdmin.pipe(take(1))])`

Comment: I think I found the issue. I moved to `BehaviorSubject` instead of Subject, which keep the last value and it now goes a bit further. The issue I now have is that when the Guard is called, the role are not yet updated :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a `ReplaySubject` which emits the latest value. A subject only emits when there is an active subscription, and a `BehaviorSubject` always emits as it starts with an initial value

```
readonly _isLoggedIn = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
readonly _isAdmin = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
```

Comment: You're right! I initially tought that a `ReplaySubject` with 1 in the constructor would be the same as a `BehaviorSubject`, but that's actually not true! But the difference is that you don't have to provide the initial value and then you can make sure it is at least initialized once! That's brillant, thank you!

Comment: @J4N exactly, the `1` indicates how many "history frames" a new subscriber should receive when subscribing. You always want the latest value, regardless of what happened before, so `1` is what you need